# Popular GridView com dados Access

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Eu consegui fazer isso em `VB.NET`, porém agora eu preciso fazer isso em `C#`e não consigo transformar o código da forma correta.

Eu tenho esse GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="BatchID" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchID" HeaderText="BatchID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BatchID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchSize" HeaderText="BatchSize" SortExpression="BatchSize" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartReq" HeaderText="StartReq" SortExpression="StartReq" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Os dados que eu coloco nele, trago por meio de um banco Access que eu criei. Em `VB.NET` eu consegui fazer funcionar, porém preciso fazer esse código funcionar em `C#` agora.

Esse é o código em `VB.NET` que preciso passar para `C#`

```
Private Sub GridView1_LoadData(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dtAllBatches As New Northwind.AllBatchesDataTable
        Using da As New NorthwindTableAdapters.AllBatchesTableAdapter
            da.Fill(dtAllBatches)
        End Using
            GridView1.DataSource = dtAllBatches.DefaultView
            GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Eu estava fazendo em `VB.NET`, porém me enganei e era pra ser feito em `C#`.
Eu tentei procurar uma forma de fazer dar certo, na internet, mas não consegui achar algo que me ajudasse e pelo menos entender como devo fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que ajude.

```
string strProvider = "@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ArquivoAcess.accdb";
string strSql = "Select * from [Nome_Tabela]";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
con.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable tabelaTmp = new DataTable();
da.Fill(tabelaTmp);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tabelaTmp;
```

Comment: Eu usei como me falou, mas só deu erro. Não deu certo.

Comment: Qual erro que deu ?

Comment: Esse:
Unrecognized escape sequence
Na área onde direciono onde está o arquivo Access
E também, na mesma linha, dá erro que falta `;` . Porém não consigo entender porque, sendo que tem no final da linha.